# Define which ID should stay on JOIN tables query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am using the following `SELECT`

```
"SELECT 
   P.id
  ,P.price
  ,P.contract
  ,P.property_type


  ,CT.id
  ,CT.english_text
  ,PT.id
  ,PT.english
  ,C.cityname
  ,S.sectorname
  ,S.id


FROM properties P
JOIN contract CT
  ON CT.id = P.contract
JOIN property_type PT
  ON PT.id = P.property_type
JOIN city C
  ON C.id = P.city
JOIN sector S
  ON S.id = P.sector WHERE 1"
```

It occur that in the final result I always have `id=2`, which I think is the id from `S.id` since it is the last one.

How I can get in foreach loop of this query to display `P.id` inside `$row['id']` ?

Right now is always `$row['2']` on each result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple columns with the same name, which confuses php.  Use aliases to give them different names:

```
SELECT P.id as p_id, P.price, P.contract, P.property_type,
       CT.id as c_id, CT.english_text,
       PT.id as pt_id, PT.english
       C.cityname,
       S.sectorname, S.id as s_id
. . .
```

This removes *all* `id`s from the result set.  What you want is called `s_id`.